# How can I learn SPML

Tags: xml-parsing

I am a beginner with SPML and would like to learn it for my work. I've searched a lot but I haven't found a tutorial. I don't know what I need for this, what tools I need to have and how to start programming SPML. I need step by step instructions. how do i proceed? Can I do that with eclipse?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Here is a link to the official documentation for version 2.
https://docs.oasis-open.org/provision/spml-2.0-cd-01/pstc-spml2-cd-01.pdf

It is a framework for XML so you should probably already know XML.

Comment: Hello Austin, thanks for reply. I had already seen this documentation. This is only a general description of SPLML and its modules, how to use them. But I'm just missing the basics at this point. E.g. how do I start, how do I set up a framework for SPML (e.g. eclipse) and how do I run an SPML program ... Thanks